# How to get most frequently executed queries in snowflakes

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Like to know is there a better way(cost efficient way) to get  more frequently executed queries? in snowflakes along with its count? and run time for each query during each time the query was called.

I know we can use  below to get few  details as per the above requirement but not all .But here  its using information_schema.query_history. I believe it adds up to the bill for each time we run this query unlike `SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY`.

Please help me with most cost effective solution as we like to run this more times during the initial days to identify and optimize the long running /more frequent queries.

```
select hash(query_text), 
    query_text, 
    count(*), 
    avg(compilation_time), 
    avg(execution_time)
from table( information_schema.query_history(
                dateadd('hours', -1, current_timestamp() ), 
                current_timestamp() ) 
          )
group by 1, 2
order by 3 desc;
```

Comment: Why do the hash() function?  Leave that out and it'd be more efficient.  This is the only way I know of doing this currently.

Comment: This is the only way to identify the same sql statements in snowflakes .Here i am interested to get the count of the same sql statements that's running in snowflakes Intention :Asking this question here not to optimize the given query that i pasted above.Looking for the other best alternative to do it.

Comment: You are grouping by both the hash and the query_text. I think Mike is saying that you can exclude the hash and just group on the query_text and it'll do the same thing.

Comment: Is there a way to get the similar queries executing with different values in where predicates?the above query in original post  only helps to get the count of same queries but not the same queries with different values in where prdiciates.How to get that

Comment: Can someone help me with this?  My intention is to catch similar queries running with different variable values.